# How to do voice chat with iChat by configuring Google account

Tags: gmail, ichat, chat

I have a Gmail account. I have configure it with my iChat. I can do normal chat, but I can not do voice chat with my other friends who have a Gmail account or are using Google Talk. So, how can I configure my iChat to do voice chat with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need iChat as a client on both ends. After this it will be automatically available.

Answer (score 0):

You need Google's voice and video chat plugin 
http://www.google.com/chat/video

Then you should be able to voice (or video) chat with your Gchat friends